# Can messages on an Exchange Server be tampered with by a client user?

Tags: exchange-server

Is ist possible for a user connected to Exchange Server via a client (Outlook Web App) to tamper with the e-mails in his mailbox (inbox, drafts, sent items ect.)?

Like modifying e-mail content (text, subject...) or properties (date, time, recipient...).

The core of the question is: If there is an e-mail in the user's sent items folder and this user did not have access to the Exchange Server (neither physically nor remotely, except for his standard user access), how sure (or probable) ist it, that this e-mail has really been sent on that date and time with exactly that text to exactly those recipients and that it had not been planted there at a later date?

Does it make a difference if that user only has access to his account via Outlook Web App or if he also has access via MS Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Web App is just a client so it won't allow you to modify a sent email or fake/import one as that is not a valid task for that client. You could do this at the API level using something like EWS or MAPI but that would require knowledge that most users won't have (but most likly they would have access to do it though). The Mitigation to this is if you have Litigation hold enabled https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861123%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx on the mailbox then any changes they did make to a message would be tracked and you would always be able to see the original version. Also if you looked at the message with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy there would be tell tails of somebody trying to fake a message like the Creation time not matching the sent time etc and other properties would most likly give it away.

One thing i would suggest is look at your Message Tracking log as they will tell you exactly what was sent and who is was sent to and the time https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124375%28v=exchg.160%29.aspx while these also aren't immutable it would take an administrative access to the server to modify.

Comment: Assumed that Litigation Hold is not enabled and the Message Tracking log is not available due to circular logging and the messages in question being a few years old, would it be possible to detect it if somebody had tried to fake something? Like the creation time you mentioned or other things?
Administrative access to the server ruled out.

Comment: All i can do is suggest you look at the messages with a MAPI editor and try to determine that yourself eg look at all the datetime properties etc. Given the age it will be hard to prove either way.